# Mulesoft integration with api and database

Tags: api, integration, mulesoft

How to extract data from api and push the output to database by using mulesoft anypoint studio 7.9 version??

Comment: The question is too broad. Also note that Anypoint Studio is an IDE to develop Mule applications. The applications have to be deployed and execute inside a Mule Runtime. It can be on prem, on cloud (CloudHub) or in Anypoint Runtime Fabric.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common and broad question, [refer this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/consuming-a-rest-api) to get an idea on how to access REST api in mulesoft and [this for Database connectivity](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.9/). There are tons of [free self paced tutorials you can take.](https://help.learn.mulesoft.com/hc/en-us/categories/115001475268-Self-paced-Training-Free-)

If you have made some progress, post your progress so someone can help with errors you are getting.